# Google map custom marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using Markerclusterer with google maps. My code is very similar to the example they provide.

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);

var markers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.photos[i].latitude,
      data.photos[i].longitude);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({'position': latLng});
  markers.push(marker);
}
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
```

This works fine as it stands. Currently I have custom markers with custom info per marker. If I use it normally then everything is fine. If i try and use Markerclusterer with it, it doesn't cluster the markers. It will only cluster the markers if I do not use a custom marker.

Does anybody know how to use a custom marker with markerclusterer. i'm not refering to a custom clusteredmarker, but the  individual markers

Comment: The MarkerClusterer should work just fine with custom markers.  Please post the code you are using that doesn't work (the code in your question does not include custom markers).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Did you manage to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

See how it is done [here](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/examples/advanced_example.html?)

You need to pass in a [ClusterIconStyle](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html#ClusterIconStyle) as follows

```
var styles = [[{
    url: '../images/people35.png',
    height: 35,
    width: 35,
    anchor: [16, 0],
    textColor: '#ff00ff',
    textSize: 10
  },
...


markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
      maxZoom: zoom,
      gridSize: size,
      styles: style[styles]
});
```

Comment: the url for the example changed, it´s now: https://googlemaps.github.io/v3-utility-library/packages/markerclustererplus/examples/advanced_example.html